# Xdebug doesn't work with phpstorm

Tags: xdebug, phpstorm

Trying to set up XDebug with PhpStorm. I installed and configured it following this guide:
https://jtreminio.com/2012/07/xdebug-and-you-why-you-should-be-using-a-real-debugger/

At the moment it looks like that. I start a session, PhpStorm ask or asked me what connection to listen. There was just one file to select. app_dev.php (It's the index from Symfony) so I selected it. Wondering why there is just one file. Now I can only debug this only file. Everythign else doesn't work. Later, the pop up came again and I selected the project folder, but still. I can just debug the app_dev.php file. What is wrong with my settings?

I also heard, I can make the debugging without having to set the session, is this true? VIa xdebug.remote_autosrat = 1?

Xdebug php info: http://pastebin.com/LQGY7t0E
Xdebug php.ini settings: http://pastebin.com/8WjKWDZk
The settings in phpstorm are like this https://jtreminio.com/assets/posts/2012-07-05_xdebug-and-you-why-you-should-be-using-a-real-debugger/phpstorm.php_.debug_.png but I do have a external connection settings because i have anewer version. (I guess). Leave it as default.

I'm using ubuntu instaleld on a VM. I'm on Win7. I created a network map to Z: and connected with phpstorm to Z:

So, any hints on how a I can get it working?

Comment: The problem **most likely** is in your path mappings (Settings | PHP | Servers) -- most likely they are incomplete. About `remote_autostart` -- yes (no bookmarklet/cookie will be required -- xdebug will attempt to debug every single request automatically). BTW -- that manual seems to be good -- I had a rather quick look on it and it seems to cover almost all (if not all) aspects for normal remote debug, so I would expect it to work as long as you follow it.

Comment: The mapping is correct. I don't know why phpstorm should get the mapping. Do I have to add every single file by hand?

Comment: http://t80i.img-up.net/foo2aef9.jpg

Comment: *"I don't know why phpstorm should get the mapping."* Maybe because IDE **needs to know** how to map REMOTE path to LOCAL one (Linux on VM and Windows on local).

Comment: Of course, forget this sentence. Rather meant why I should have to mape every single file, which you probably don't have to.

Comment: You do not have to -- all subfolders/files will inherit mappings from parent folder. In simplest case only root folder needs to be mapped. Additional mappings are required only if you have multiple content roots (each content root has it's own mapping point); symbolic links are used (on remote side); external libraries entries (since they have the same logic in this regard as content roots).

Comment: Okay, but anyway. It still doesn't work and I absolutely don't know why.

Comment: The only other suggestion I can think of right now is to: **1)** try xdebug 2.2.3 instead of 2.3 (it's still work in progress) **2)** collect debug-related logs from both PhpStorm and xdebug sides as advised here: http://devnet.jetbrains.com/thread/449304

Comment: Does the xdebug support differ if you just open an directory or if you actually create a project?

Comment: Project is created in both cases (IDE works with projects only, it's a requirement -- it does not work with "just a random collection of files"). If you wish -- backup and delete (or just rename) project settings while project is closed in IDE -- they are located in `.idea` subfolder. Maybe you have configured it somehow (or some glitch, whatever) and fresh start can make a difference.

Comment: Anyway, thanks. I'll investigate and try until it works and post it here.